# Telerik RadGrid.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel() Error: The query results enumerated more than once

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I have a RadGrid which is populated with some data.  I have a button which will Export to Excel via a serverside callback.  The server side code is below.  And the error below that.  Any suggestions?

```
RadGrid1.Rebind();
   RadGrid1.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = true;
   RadGrid1.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();
```

The error is:

> The query results cannot be enumerated more than once.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The query results cannot be enumerated more than once.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The query results cannot be enumerated more than once.]
>      System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.OneTimeEnumerable`1.GetEnumerator() +884205
>      System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SingleResult`1.GetEnumerator() +76
>      System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +302
>      System.Linq.d__0.MoveNext() +164
>      System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +163
>      Telerik.Web.UI.GridResolveEnumerable.GetCollectionItemType(Boolean noItemsInEnumerator, Type& collectionItemType, Object& collectionFirstObject) +330
>      Telerik.Web.UI.GridResolveEnumerable.ParseProperties() +120
>      Telerik.Web.UI.GridResolveEnumerable.Initialize() +16
>      Telerik.Web.UI.GridResolveEnumerable.EnsureInitialized() +28
>      Telerik.Web.UI.GridEnumerableFromDataView..ctor(GridTableView owner, IEnumerable enumerable, Boolean CaseSensitive, Boolean autoGenerateColumns, GridColumnCollection presentColumns, String[] additionalField, Boolean retrieveAllFields) +242
>      Telerik.Web.UI.GridDataSourceHelper.CreateGridEnumerable(GridTableView owner, IEnumerable enumerable, Boolean caseSensitive, Boolean autoGenerateColumns, GridColumnCollection presentColumns, String[] additionalField, Boolean retrieveAllFields) +223
>      Telerik.Web.UI.GridDataSourceHelper.GetResolvedDataSource(GridTableView owner, Object dataSource, String dataMember, Boolean caseSensitive, Boolean autoGenerateColumns, GridColumnCollection presentColumns, String[] additionalField, Boolean retrieveAllFields) +595
>      Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.get_ResolvedDataSource() +243
>      Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean useDataSource) +42
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +72
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data) +147
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +261
>      Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.PerformSelect() +9
>      Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.DataBind() +363
>      Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.DataBind() +73
>      Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.AutoDataBind(GridRebindReason rebindReason) +2488
>      Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.RebindForExport() +119
>      Telerik.Web.UI.Grid.Export.TableViewExporter.PrepareForExport() +315
>      System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e) +0
>      System.Web.UI.Control.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +11056782
>      System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +108
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3394

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to call `Rebind()` before the export.  Is there a reason for that?  Are you changing/manipulating the data right before the export?

If not, there is no need to call `Rebind()`, since that is really only meant to refresh the data source.